# View Scheduled Emails in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am consulting with a group that has several users on their GA account. How can I see the scheduled email each person set up to make sure they're correct and do I can assist them when they have problems?

If it can't be done, can someone please point me to an official Google statement saying it can't be done?...at least that way I can tell my boss :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That cant be done. As to pointing you to Googles Statement of why it cant be done the only thing I can give you is the current documentation for the API.

IMO this feature would be located in the Management API probably under User permissions but i'm not really sure that's the best place for it either.

[User Permissions - Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtUserPermissions)

I feel this is a very good idea and added it to my long list of feature requests feel free to star it.   [Manage Scheduled Emails](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=421)  Now I'm not sure they will add it I think they may decided that there is to grate a spam risk with this.  But we will have to wait and see.

Tell your boss that its not currently available in the Google Analytics API but a feature request was made.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the gear icon in the bottom left, then on the bottom right under 'Personal Tools & Assets', you should see Scheduled Emails. They're only visible with the view they're attached to, so if you have multiple views, you'll need to look through each one.